# Nginx directs request to www.example.com but not to internal web application

Tags: nginx

I've installed several web applications on different ports on the same server. From that server when I send an http request using wget or curl the request goes through  and I get the response. I've set up nginx server to not have to specify the port each time. Here's the related nginx config:

```
server {
  listen                10.0.223.34:80;
  server_name           app1.domain.com;
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app1.domain.com.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/app1.domain.com.error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_pass          http://10.0.223.34:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

If I try `app1.domain.com` from outside I get `502 Bad gateway` error. But if I change the `proxy_pass` to `http:\\www.example.com`, then nginx takes me to the example.com website.

Inside the nginx.conf file I've specified `user nginx;`. I've tried changing it to root but it didn't help either. Do you have any idea what else I need to check?

Comment: What happens when you open http://10.0.223.34:8080?

Comment: What type of server listens on port 8080? Do you have some network monitor like WireShark. You could compare the packets that arrive on port 80 and the packets that are send to port 8080

Comment: @ThomasSablik, that port is closed to outside, only 80 is open.

Comment: Tomcat is listening on port 8080. BTW, in the nginx logs I found this: `no live upstreams while connecting to upstream ....`. So it looks as if the service nginx is trying to reach is down. But it's not, because I can reach it with wget or curl.

Comment: The port is closed but you can reach it with curl or wget? Could you explain it?

Comment: Try `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;`. The server is configured to disallow other connections.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, port is closed to outside. But I send reqeust with curl and wget from within the same server. I'm sorry, I somehow thought you mean from another machine with brwoser, when you asked "What happens when you open 10.0.223.34:8080?"

Comment: I've tried both `http://localhost:8080` and `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. Neither one worked.

Comment: Did you try to monitor the requests?

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I'll try to monitor it and will inform the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
upstream app1 {
    server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    listen 10.0.223.34:
    server_name           app1.domain.com;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/app1.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/app1.domain.com.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```